# Toolbar with EditText material design

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I'm trying to make Toolbar with EditText within it like this:

[image: Toolbar with EditText]

Right now I can do some thing similar but only with static title, Any ideas to get started?

Comment: Can't you just put EditTexts in a AppBarLayout? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: Yes, but i want The EditText to turn into normal TextView and smoothly go smaller when the user scrolls up.

Comment: use appbarlayout and collapsible toolbar

Comment: MoHaKa, how can EditText be scrolled  to title position when user scroll upward.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have done this like below:

[image]

There is `Toolbar` as `AppBar` (aka `ActionBar`) at the top and second toolbar below it with two `EditText`. First Toolbar is under `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in case you want it to be collapsed.

`Java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lNameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fNameLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ltitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Title"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lNameLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fNameLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ldesc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Description"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`Colors`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="accent">#00E5FF</color>

</resources>
```

And `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

Use `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` for application in manifest and `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base" for`MainActivity`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I just want to ask about what happens if user scrolls up?

Comment: İt depends on you, use `scrollFlags` to control it. You can fix both tabs or one, or can hide them while scrolling.

Comment: but title does not become toolbar title in above implementation when you scroll

Comment: Can i make the title EditText turns into TextView and goes smaller up to activity title place while scrolling?

Comment: Hi this is nice, why are there 2 toolbars here? What does the other one do?

Comment: @NeonWarge 2nd `Toolbar` contains that `EditText`s on top. You can use `LinearLayout` too i guess

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use `scrollFlags` to hide 2nd `edittext` and show 1st `edittext` when scrolled up?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create you own toolbarlyout and set it to the activity toolbar.
try this :

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android
you just need to create your component.
i hope that will be helpful for you ;)

Comment: Do you have an idea to make smooth scrolling while the user scrolls up and down?

Comment: I want The EditText to turn into normal TextView and smoothly go smaller when the user scrolls up.

Comment: Why don't you just toggle visibility with an TextView which is located at the same position and animate this when scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linear layout with the same color of your toolbar. The toolbar attribute `android:elevation` needs to be `0px`.

Activity (xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_task"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></include>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment_task"
              android:name="com.hashicode.simpletodo.fragment.TaskFragment" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_task"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="0px">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Fragment (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/taskname_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/PrimaryDarkColor"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="36dp"
                android:paddingLeft="72dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/task_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/task.name"
                    android:textSize="30dp"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

         <!-- some code -->

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity (java)

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initializeTodo(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);
        //set the toolbar
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    }
```

The result:

[image]