# FloatingActionButton is not displaying in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, floating-action-button

Hi I need to display 2 `EditText` and `FloatingActionButton` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I have  used [this Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636574/how-to-fix-a-view-in-collapsing-toolbar-while-scrolling) to display `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but my `FloatingActionButton` is not visible in Real Device(Redmi Note 4).

**XML CODE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="136dp">
    -->1st textView
 </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    -->2nd TextView

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
          app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
          app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```

[image: output layout iam getting]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: can you attach the layout image you are getting

Comment: I have attached the image iam getting

Comment: Check my answer. However, that would be great to see the whole code since you got a `NavigationView` in there too.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted is not the full code neither has `NavigationView` since the picture you provided shows that there is a `NavigationView` (with at least a `DrawerLayout`) which contains `CoordinatorLayout` and etc.

However, this code works:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Perhaps you need "`+`" in `app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"` or, there is another problem with the `DrawerLayout` if this code didn't help. Also, make sure `CoordinatorLayout` is the child of `DrawerLayout` at the end.

Comment: I have navigation in my main activity and it contains 4 fragment and i need collapsingtoolbar in one of my fragment...thank you for your code but where I can get 2 edit text  in collapsing toolbar